# All post by same user in a group, how to find them in one screen?

Tags: facebook-groups

Sometimes in a group if I press the name of the user instead of taking me to their profile shows me all activity of that member in the group since joining but that’s not always the case, other times it just shows me their profiles son how to choose if I want the activity or the profile? Thanks